# Is there a stack exchange for people learning math?

Tags: support

I am a student who is interested in mathematics, and as such, often have questions about it.  Asking on Math Stack Exchange is an option, but I'm not sure that my questions really fit with the site, as they are not *nearly* as advanced as the others on the site.  (Although they are above the level of homework questions.)

Is this the right site for me, or is there another Stack Exchange site that would be better suited to my needs?

Comment: Yes, here is the right place for you as long as you ask ["good questions"](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: If they are above the level of "how to solve for $x$ in $3x = 2$", that's a good start already.

Comment: The [description of this site](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) says (emphasis mine): "Mathematics Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people studying math *at any level* and professionals in related fields."

Comment: Do not come here and ask us to do your homework for you.   The site is not for "opinion" or "discussion" questions.  But if you avoid these pitfalls, you will be fine.

Comment: @GEdgar I know enough about Stack Exchange to avoid the "pitfalls" that you of which you so kindly informed me.  I sincerely thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use this for learning maths and "good" questions will be answered, but be sure to see if your question has been asked before, which it often has if you search thoroughly first before asking it yourself.

Comment: Mathematics Stack Exchange is for people studying maths at any level. Beginners will nevertheless find maths snobs criticising you for simple questions. Just make sure you up vote the others.